ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" when using @Query
In my Postgres database, I have a table called ts_kv
id       | key       | json_v
——————————----------------------
UUID | Integer | json

The value of json_v is like
[{"ts":61000,"eui64”:”f4dddhhsd”,”volume":0}]

What I want to do, is to find all latest entries for each distinct eui64 entry.
Let's say I have a few entries on this database with below json_v
[{"ts":10,"eui64":"f4ce777776470","volume":0}]
[{"ts":10,"eui64":"f4ce777776471","volume":0}] 
[{"ts":10,"eui64":"f4ce777776472","volume":0}] 
[{"ts":20,"eui64":"f4ce777776471","volume":50}] 
[{"ts":20,"eui64":"f4ce777776472","volume":50}] 

I have a sql query to retrieve the latest record for each eui64 from the ts_kv table,
WITH ranked_data AS (
    SELECT
        json_v,
        json_v->>'eui64' AS eui64,
        (json_v->>'ts')::bigint AS ts,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY json_v->>'eui64' ORDER BY (json_v->>'ts')::bigint DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ts_kv
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ranked_data
WHERE
    rn = 1;

which returns
[{"ts":10,"eui64":"f4ce777776470","volume":0}] 

[{"ts":20,"eui64":"f4ce777776471","volume": 50}] 
[{"ts":20,"eui64":"f4ce777776472","volume":50}] 

However, when I tried to make it a query using @Query,
@Query(value = "WITH ranked_data AS ( " +
        "    SELECT " +
        "        json_v, " +
        "        json_v->>'eui64' AS eui64, " +
        "        (json_v->>'ts')::bigint AS ts, " +
        "        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY json_v->>'eui64' ORDER BY (json_v->>'ts')::bigint DESC) AS rn " +
        "    FROM " +
        "        ts_kv " +
        ") " +
        "SELECT " +
        "    * " +
        "FROM " +
        "    ranked_data " +
        "WHERE " +
        "    rn = 1", nativeQuery = true)
List<TsKvEntity> findLatest();

It throws an error
{
    "status": 500,
    "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
    "errorCode": 2,
    "timestamp": "2024-06-13T20:56:13.084+00:00"
}

And I then checked the console
    WITH ranked_data AS (     SELECT
        json_v,
        json_v->>'eui64' AS eui64,
        (json_v->>'ts'):bigint AS ts,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION 
    BY
        json_v->>'eui64' 
    ORDER BY
        (json_v->>'ts'):bigint DESC) AS rn     
    FROM
        ts_kv ) SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        ranked_data 
    WHERE
        rn = 1
Hibernate: 
    WITH ranked_data AS (     SELECT
        json_v,
        json_v->>'eui64' AS eui64,
        (json_v->>'ts'):bigint AS ts,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION 
    BY
        json_v->>'eui64' 
    ORDER BY
        (json_v->>'ts'):bigint DESC) AS rn     
    FROM
        ts_kv ) SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        ranked_data 
    WHERE
        rn = 1
2024-06-13 13:56:13,082 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2024-06-13 13:56:13,082 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 108 

However I couldn’t identity where line causes the error. Does anyone has any idea? 

As :bigint would be a parameter placeholder, could it be that?

Your value has typographic quotes, where only plain double-quotes are valid syntax:
Wrong:
[{"ts":61000,"eui64”:”f4dddhhsd”,”volume":0}]

Right:
[{"ts":61000,"eui64":"f4dddhhsd","volume":0}]

test=> SELECT ascii('"') AS plain,  ascii('”') AS typo;
 plain | typo 
-------+------
    34 | 8221

The value does not error out right away, because the last double-quote is correct so it parses like this:
test=> SELECT * FROM jsonb_each('{"ts": 61000, "eui64”:”f4dddhhsd”,”volume": 0}');
            key             | value 
----------------------------+-------
 ts                         | 61000
 eui64”:”f4dddhhsd”,”volume | 0

That's a downsides of UNICODE: tons of lookalike characters that only spread confusion.
Another syntax error in your test in the console:
Short cast syntax is ::bigint not :bigint. See:

Postgres data type cast

While being at it, a cheaper and shorter way ...

to retrieve the latest record for each eui64 from the ts_kv table

SELECT DISTINCT ON (json_v->>'eui64')
       json_v  -- more?
FROM   ts_kv
ORDER  BY json_v->>'eui64', (json_v->>'ts')::bigint DESC;

See:

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?


Thanks for your answer, but [{"ts":61000,"eui64":"f4dddhhsd","volume":0}] is an array instead of object, so the query result is not correct. Just wondering if it's possible to query it without changing the data shape?

@ERTY: What query result? My DISTINCT ON query? Strip the noise array wrapper with json_v->0->>'eui64' etc.
